# How to scroll the window automatically when mouse moves bottom of the page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have 50 divs,But in my window it shows only 25,I do drag and drop activity on these divs.So If i drag my first div near 25th div,It should scroll automatically to show the remaining divs.How do i do this in jquery? any idea?

I am using [Nestable](http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/) not draggable()

Comment: Scroll events can be triggered manually as explained here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.scroll

However, because you are specifically using jQuery's drag and drop I thought dragging an element to the bottom of the browser window triggered the scroll event anyways?

Comment: How to know when bottom of window is reached on element drag?

Comment: I thought it did that automatically. http://ktstowell.github.io/angular-file-utils/#/ I use drag and drop here. When I drag and item on the left down to the bottom of the window the browser scrolls to the content below the fold.

Comment: Can you add your specific code to the question? It may help others who are having similar problems in the future.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will need some fine tuning depending on your specific use case but it seems to work fairly well.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5hLk2/6/)**

```
$('.dd').nestable({ /* config options */
});

$(window).mousemove(function (e) {
    var x = $(window).innerHeight() - 50,
        y = $(window).scrollTop() + 50;
    if ($('.dd-dragel').offset().top > x) {
        //Down
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 300 // adjust number of px to scroll down
        }, 600);
    }
    if ($('.dd-dragel').offset().top < y) {
        //Up
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 600);
    } else {
        $('html, body').animate({

        });
    }
});
```

**Related API documentation:**

- [.mousemove()](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/)
- [.innerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/)
- [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)
- [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)
- [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Thanks, this was I expected. This script works fine. Thank you verry much.

Comment: This is honestly really unpleasant. If I keep moving the mouse around the bottom, it doesn't scroll down because the animations cancel each other out, and then if I move back *away* from the bottom it starts scrolling some predetermined amount. Furthermore it doesn't update the state of the item you're dragging until/unless you move the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know bottom of window you can check

```
$(window).height()
```

and `$(window).scrollTop()`;

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic but since this feature keeps in standby, I just improved apaul34208's code, hope it helps

```
$(window).mousemove(function (e) {
    if ($('.dd-dragel') && $('.dd-dragel').length > 0 && !$('html, body').is(':animated')) {
        var bottom = $(window).height() - 50,
            top = 50;

        if (e.clientY > bottom && ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $(document).height() - 100)) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 300
            }, 600);
        }
        else if (e.clientY < top && $(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - 300
            }, 600);
        } else {
            $('html, body').finish();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This fixes the cancellation of other animations, but still isn't great. The transition is nonlinear, so it sorta starts and stops assuming you're moving the mouse around the scroll-down area. If you're not moving the mouse around when it finishes the animation it'll stop scrolling until you do move a pixel, even if for instance you had paused on the scroll-down area and were starting to move the mouse away from it.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of an improvement on Mencey's code. A caveat it might have is that it's based on an interval fired every 16 milliseconds instead of mousemove(). I don't know how taxing this may be, so feel free to increase the number of milliseconds or fire a clearInterval at some point. The benefit from this is the scrolling is continuous, instead of having to wiggle the mouse as 1j01 pointed out.

You may also change the `speed` and `zone` variables, `zone` being an area in pixels at the top and the bottom of the window where you can drag the item. As you get closer to the top or the bottom of the window, the scrolling speed goes up as it compares the distance between the position of the mouse and the actual edge of the window, giving some control to the user on the scrolling speed.

```
var mouseY;
var speed = 0.15;
var zone = 50; 

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
   mouseY = e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop();
}).mouseover();

var dragInterval = setInterval(function(){

  if ($('.dd-dragel') && $('.dd-dragel').length > 0 && !$('html, body').is(':animated')) {
    var bottom = $(window).height() - zone;

  if (mouseY > bottom && ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $(document).height() - zone)) {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:  $(window).scrollTop() + ((mouseY + zone - $(window).height()) * speed)},0);
  }
  else if (mouseY < zone && $(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + ( (mouseY - zone) * speed) },0);

  } else {
     $('html, body').finish();
  }
  }
},16);
```