# How to make the scrolling script efficiently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I have div element inside that I have a list of(ol) elements. I use drag and drop using jquery nestable. Please look at the issue here ([How to scroll the window automatically when mouse moves bottom of the page using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17895141/how-to-scroll-the-window-automatically-when-mouse-moves-bottom-of-the-page-using)).

I used to get the visible `<li>` in current view, using view-port(plugin - http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport).

I used the below script. I couldn't scroll the page more efficient and
script doesn't work in FF (scrolling does not work).

```
if ($('.dd-dragel').length > 0) {
  var totalVisibleLi = $('#ol_id li:visible').length;
  var liInViewPort = $('#ol_id li:in-viewport').length;
  var closestLi = $(this.placeEl).prev('li');
  var items = $('#ol_id li:in-viewport');
  var indexOfClosestLi = items.index(closestLi);

  if (indexOfClosestLi >= (liInViewPort - 3) && (e.pageY < $('#div_id').height())) {

    $('body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 200
    }, 1);
  }

  if (indexOfClosestLi <= 3) {
    $('body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - 200
    }, 1);

  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Firstly, for FF, you need: ` $('body,html').animate({...})`. I just check the link you posted and the answer use it: `$('html,body')` So what is your problem? Couldn't you start by using code other trying to help you had posted?!

Comment: Scroll is working, but it is not smooth as expected. scroll upwards behaves unexpectedly

Comment: My comment was to answer your statement: <<and script doesn't work in FF>> So if it works on FF, don't post that... BTW, for smooth scrolling i'd suggest to use instead CSS3 transition but it is a little more complicated and not supported on older browsers

Comment: If you can post the related code and a jsFiddle I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Edited your code. Now scroll also work in FF

```
if ($('.dd-dragel').length > 0) {
  var totalVisibleLi = $('#ol_id li:visible').length;
  var liInViewPort = $('#ol_id li:in-viewport').length;
  var closestLi = $(this.placeEl).prev('li');
  var items = $('#ol_id li:in-viewport');
  var indexOfClosestLi = items.index(closestLi);

  if (indexOfClosestLi >= (liInViewPort - 3) && (e.pageY < $('#div_id').height())) {

    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 200
    }, 400);
  }

  if (indexOfClosestLi <= 3) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - 200
    }, 400);

  }
}
```

Comment: after changing the selector $('html,body') it works in FF. But this is not a smooth scroll.

Comment: just add speed 400 instead of 1

Comment: @rajini, After increasing animation speed to 400, still I am facing the same problem

Comment: can you point me to use CSS3 transitions, or is there any mistake in my script?